# Symmetric Difference Along 3 Sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was doing an assignment where I had to choose from answer choices to answer the following expression:

$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N \oplus \mathbb Q$

The choices were $\sqrt2$, -1, 1, -2, and $\sqrt5$, respectively.

However, I got stumped. I know the definition of $A \oplus B$ is

$\{x \in A \; \land x\notin B \} \lor \{x \notin A \; \land x\in B \}$

I reasoned that this set was then just the set of all irrational numbers, which stumped me because $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt5$ are both irrational. I chose $\sqrt2$ because I was crunched for time. However, it's really bothering me, and I'd like to know how this is done, accurately.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N $ means x is an integer but not positive or X is not an integer but is a positive integer.  In other words x is a non-postive integer.

$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N \oplus \mathbb Q$ therefore means x is either a non-positive integer that isn't rational (impossible) or a rational that isn't an non-positive integer.  So x is a rational that isn't a non-positive integer.

1 is the only possibility.

===
or 
$\mathbb N \oplus \mathbb Q$ or that natural numbers that aren't rational (impossible) or the rationals that aren't positive integers.

$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N \oplus \mathbb Q$ is therefore the integers that aren't  rationals that aren't positive integers, i.e. the positive integers, or the rationals that aren't positive integers that aren't intergers, i.e. non-integer rationals.  i.e. the rationals that aren't non-positive integers, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Since symmetric difference is associative: $ \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N \oplus \mathbb Q = \left( \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N \right) \oplus \mathbb Q $
$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb N = \mathbb Z \cup \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb Z \cap \mathbb N = \{-1, -2, -3,...\}=:G$

$G \oplus \mathbb Q = G \cup \mathbb Q \setminus G \cap \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q \setminus G$ 

(Since $G \subset \mathbb Q$)

Can you see the answer?